# (Dis)Prove that the sum is positive

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, matrices, derivatives, summation

## Question

Let $\alpha \in ]0,1]$ be arbitrary and $c \in [\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha},1]$.

I have the following sum:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial c}\left[\sum_{(i_{m-1},\dots,i_0)\in \{0,1\}^{m-1}} q_{(i_{m-1},\dots, i_0)}(c)  \cdot \left(\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} i_j\right)^2 \right]
$$
with $q_{(i_{m-1},\dots, i_0)}(c) = (i_{m-1} (1-\alpha) + (1-i_{m-1}) \alpha) \cdot P_{i_{m-1},i_{m-2}}(c) \cdot \dots \cdot P_{i_1,i_0}(c)$ with
$$
P(c) = \begin{pmatrix}
(1-\alpha)c + \alpha & (\alpha - 1)c + (1-\alpha)\\
(-\alpha) c + \alpha & \alpha c + (1-\alpha)
\end{pmatrix},
$$
so for example $P_{0,1}(c)$ is just $(\alpha-1)c + (1-\alpha)$.

I would like to prove or disprove that this sum is positive.

I have proven it for the case $k = 2$ and for the general case I considered the following strategy:

## General idea

Split it up into the different possible values for $\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}i_j$, if this value is equal to $1$ the corresponding possibilities for the different $i$ are: $(1,0,\dots,0),(0,1,\dots,0),\dots,(0,\dots,0,1,0)$ and $(0,\dots,0,1)$ and for this case we get in the total sum the value:
$$
1\cdot\left((1-\alpha) P_{10} P_{00}^{m-2} + \alpha P_{10} P_{00}^{m-2} P_{01} + \alpha P_{01} P_{00}^{m-1}\right),
$$
and we can continue like this (see "start solution").

## Examples

I have done the calculations numerically for $m = 2,\dots,7$ with the following results for the sum (which are all clearly positive on the domain we're interested in):
$$
\begin{cases}
-2(\alpha - 1)\alpha\\
-4(\alpha - 1)\alpha (1+c)\\ 
-2 (\alpha-1)\alpha(3+4c+3c^2)\\ 
-4(\alpha-1)\alpha(2+3c+3c^2+2c^3)\\ 
-2(\alpha-1)\alpha (5+8c+9c^2+8c^3+5c^4)\\ 
-4(\alpha-1)\alpha (3+5c+6c^2+6c^3+5c^4+3c^5)\\ 
-2(\alpha-1)\alpha (7+12c+15c^2+16c^3+15c^4+12c^5+7c^6)
\end{cases}
$$

## Start of solution

Writing out the sum as described in "General Idea" gives us:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} n^2(2Q_1 + Q_3 + Q_4) + m^2(m-1) \cdot (1-\alpha) \cdot P_{11}^{m-2} \cdot \alpha,
$$
where
$$
\begin{cases}
Q_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n\wedge(m-n)} \binom{n-1}{k-1} \binom{m-1-n}{k-1} \alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial_c}(P_{01}^kP_{10}^{k-1}P_{00}^{m-k-n}P_{11}^{n-k})\\
Q_3 = \sum_{k=1}^{n\wedge(m-n-1)} \binom{m-n-1}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1} \alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial_c}(P_{01}^kP_{10}^kP_{00}^{m-k-n-1}P_{11}^{n-k})\\
Q_4 = \sum_{k=1}^{(n-1) \wedge (m-n)} \binom{n-1}{k} \binom{m-n-1}{k-1} (1-\alpha) \frac{\partial}{\partial_c}(P_{01}^k P_{10}^k P_{00}^{m-k-n} P_{11}^{n-k-1})
\end{cases}
$$
I have also checked this form with mathematica for the cases $k = 2,3,4,5,6,7$ that this expressions gives the same values as the original expression and it indeed does.

## Solution (Without proof)

I think I've found the solution (but I don't know how to prove it). As in the examples we write the $n$'th polynomial as:
$$
-2(\alpha-1)\alpha \cdot p_n(c)
$$
if we now write out the triangle made by the coefficients of $p_n$ we clearly see a pattern:
[image: Polynomial Coefficients]
The pattern is just:
[image: Pattern in the coefficients]
Thus we claim that in general our polynomial is given by:
$$
-2(\alpha-1)\alpha\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (j+1)\cdot(n-j)\cdot c^j\right)
$$
the only thing that remains to be done is check that this is correct, perhaps by induction.

## Proof by induction (start)

We have the following recursive formula for $q$:
$$
q_{(i_m,\dots,i_0)} = \frac{\pi_{i_k}}{\pi_{i_{k-1}}} P_{i_k,i_{k-1}} q_{(i_{k-1},\dots,i_0)},
$$
with $\pi_0 = \alpha$ and $\pi_1 = (1-\alpha)$ moreover we easily get from this:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial c} q_{(i_m,\dots,i_0)} = \frac{\pi_{i_k}}{\pi_{i_{k-1}}} \frac{\partial}{\partial c}(P_{i_k,i_{k-1}} q_{(i_{k-1},\dots,i_0)})$$

I splitted the sum over $(i_m,\dots,i_0)$ into four parts letting $(i_m,i_{m-1}) \in \{0,1\}^2$ which seems to be working pretty well.

Let us define:
$$
R_{m-1} :=
\frac{\partial}{\partial c}\left[\sum_{(i_{m-1},\dots,i_0)\in \{0,1\}^{m-1}} q_{(i_{m-1},\dots, i_0)}(c)  \cdot \left(\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} i_j\right)^2 \right]
$$

then I have shown that:
$$
R_m = R_{m-1} + \frac{\partial}{\partial c}\sum_{i_{m-1},\dots,i_0} P_{i_{m-1}1} q_{(i_{m-1},\dots,i_0)} (2\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} i_j + 1)
$$
Using this I narrowed the problem down to proving that:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial c} \sum_{(i_m,\dots,i_0)} P_{i_m1}q_{(i_m,\dots,i_0)}(2\sum_{j=0}^m i_j + 1) = -2 \alpha(\alpha-1) \left( \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} (j+1) c^j + (m+1) c^m \right)
$$
I have also checked numerically that this equality indeed holds, now we can try to prove this equality by using induction.

After some more simplificiations it remains to find an expression for:
$$
\sum_{i_{m-2},\dots,i_0} (2 \sum_{j=0}^{m-2} i_j + 1) q_{(0,i_{m-2},\dots,i_0)}.
$$

Comment: Perhaps you should exploit some actual significance of this quantity?

Comment: The thing that this quantity signifies is the thing that I wish to prove that is positive (it signifies some relation which I would like to prove is increasing, I did some simulations etc. and those suggested that this quantity should be positive), if you can prove that it can be negative that's also a nice answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself thus there is no further need for this question.